# Как программно поменять параметр android:layout_height="" у ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Есть ConstraintLayout с параметром android:layout_height="550"
Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки, значение параметра менялось на 450.
Однако все, что я нашел по этому поводу в документации, это `ConstraintLayout.setMaxHeigth();` и `ConstraintLayout.setMinHeigth();`, но при изменении этих параметров, у меня верхнюю и нижнюю части макета становится не видно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю это должно помочь

```
ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.you_layout);
// Получение LayoutParams которые позволят нам изменить размеры нашего layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Изменение высоты или ширины в пикселях
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Если вы хотите конвертировать dp в пиксели используйте этот метод

```
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, <HEIGHT>, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: К сожалению нет(
Все равно отображается только те объекты, что находятся в середине